# Fatal Exception NSRangeException -[__NSCFString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: Range {N, N} out of bounds; string length N

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm getting the following error from the code below and I'm not sure why.

**Fatal Exception NSRangeException
-[__NSCFString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: Range {0, 7} out of bounds; string length 6**

I wondered if someone could explain ?

Is it just that I need to new NSRange variable to cater for the different string length ?

```
+(double)removeFormatPrice:(NSString *)strPrice {

    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber* number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:strPrice];

    //cater for commas and create double to check against the number put 
    //through the currency formatter
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *mstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strPrice];
    NSRange wholeShebang = NSMakeRange(0, [mstring length]);

    [mstring replaceOccurrencesOfString: [formatter groupingSeparator]
                             withString: @""
                                options: 0
                                  range: wholeShebang];

    //if decimal symbol is not a decimal point replace it with a decimal point
    NSString *symbol = [[NSLocale currentLocale] 
                  objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
    if (![symbol isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        [mstring replaceOccurrencesOfString: symbol
                                 withString: @"."
                                    options: 0
                                      range: wholeShebang]; // ERROR HERE
    }

    double newPrice = [mstring doubleValue];
    if (number == nil) {
        return newPrice;
    } else {
        return [number doubleValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what?  How 7 is > 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first replacement operation has been done, the string is shorter than it was, when you constructed the range (you are replacing characters with nothing). The original initialisation

```
NSRange wholeShebang = NSMakeRange(0, [mstring length]);
```

gives now a range, whose length is too large. Example:

```
NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"1.234,5"];
NSRange allOfStr = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);

[str replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"."
                         withString: @""
                            options: 0
                              range: allOfStr];
```

Note, that `str` now looks like `1234,5`, i.e., it is shorter by one character than it was at the time, the range was initialized.

For that reason, you get the index out of bounds error, if you use the range again on the now too short string. You should re-initialize the range before passing it to the second replace op.:

```
allOfStr = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);

[str replaceOccurrencesOfString: @","
                         withString: @"."
                            options: 0
                              range: allOfStr];
```

Comment: I think the key here is that the string MAY be smaller, it may not, but I need that line to cater for both.